# Error while extracing XML data from XML file in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
DECLARE @TablesList TABLE 
(
    TableName VARCHAR(500),
    RefTable VARCHAR(500),
    RefTableIDColumn VARCHAR(500)
)
DECLARE @Query AS VARCHAR(MAX)


SET @Query = 'DECLARE @badIds AS VARCHAR(500) DECLARE @TableXML AS XML'
SET @Query = @Query + ' SELECT @TableXML = xCol FROM (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''\\10.0.0.60\Temp\path\DataItemTables.xml'', SINGLE_CLOB)AS xCol) AS R(xCol)'
SET @Query = @Query + ' INSERT INTO @TablesList SELECT ref.value(''tablename[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS tablename,'
SET @Query = @Query + ' ref.value(''refTable[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS refTable, ref.value(''refTableIDColumn[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS refTableIDColumn FROM'
SET @Query = @Query + ' @TableXML.nodes(''//Table[@name="Description"]'') AS R(ref)'
SET @Query = @Query +'select * from @TablesList'

EXEC(@Query)
```

I am executing the above script. But I am getting an error as below

```
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the table variable "@TablesList".
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the table variable "@TablesList".
```

What I am doing wrong. But when I write the query in dynamic form like below , it works fine. The problem is that I want to remove all the dynamic portion of the SP .

```
DECLARE @Query AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Query ='DECLARE @TablesList TABLE ( TableName VARCHAR(500),RefTable VARCHAR(500),RefTableIDColumn VARCHAR(500))'
SET @Query = @Query + ' DECLARE @badIds AS VARCHAR(500) DECLARE @TableXML AS XML'
SET @Query = @Query + ' SELECT @TableXML = xCol FROM (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''\\10.0.0.60\Temp\Path\DataItemTables.xml'', SINGLE_CLOB)AS xCol) AS R(xCol)'
SET @Query = @Query + ' INSERT INTO @TablesList SELECT ref.value(''tablename[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS tablename,'
SET @Query = @Query + ' ref.value(''refTable[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS refTable, ref.value(''refTableIDColumn[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS refTableIDColumn FROM'
SET @Query = @Query + ' @TableXML.nodes(''//Table[@name="Description"]'') AS R(ref)'
SET @Query = @Query +'select * from @TablesList'

EXEC(@Query)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only access a table variable in the same scope where it is declared. Since your `EXEC` is in a different scope, the table variable is not recognized. One way to solve this is to use a temp table instead:

```
CREATE TABLE #TablesList
(
    TableName VARCHAR(500),
    RefTable VARCHAR(500),
    RefTableIDColumn VARCHAR(500)
)
DECLARE @Query AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Query = 'DECLARE @badIds AS VARCHAR(500) DECLARE @TableXML AS XML'
SET @Query = @Query + ' SELECT @TableXML = xCol FROM (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''\\10.0.0.60\Temp\path\DataItemTables.xml'', SINGLE_CLOB)AS xCol) AS R(xCol)'
SET @Query = @Query + ' INSERT INTO #TablesList SELECT ref.value(''tablename[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS tablename,'
SET @Query = @Query + ' ref.value(''refTable[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS refTable, ref.value(''refTableIDColumn[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS refTableIDColumn FROM'
SET @Query = @Query + ' @TableXML.nodes(''//Table[@name="Description"]'') AS R(ref)'
SET @Query = @Query +'select * from #TablesList'

EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Can I make the above query more static rather than dynamic.?

Comment: Sure, I'll leave it to you as an exercise.

Comment: @user2998990 Do you have any reason to use dynamic SQL? If you change the `EXEC (@Query)` to a ``SELECT @Query` you'll get the query's text without big work, just some littel formatting. Don't forget to set the text length to 8192 (max value) for the output, otherwise SSMS will not show you the whole lot...